# JavaFX - Wrapping FXML to Java Class Controller

Tags: java, treeview, javafx, fxml

I have a FXML file that has a TreeView control:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="test.MyControllerClass">

<TreeView fx:id="locationTreeView" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="158.0" prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="471.0" />
```

Then my Java Class Controller needs to wrap with this TreeView and add TreeItem's dynamically. That's the problem, it isn't loading those TreeItem's. That's the test code below, from my Controller:

```
public class MyControllerClass extends Application {

    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> locationTreeView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myIcon.png")));

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("myInterface.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        loadTreeItems();

        stage.show();
    }

    // Just a simple example that still doesn't works
    private void loadTreeItems() {

        try {
            TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Root Node");
            root.setExpanded(true);
            root.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<String>("Item 1"),
                new TreeItem<String>("Item 2"),
                new TreeItem<String>("Item 3")
            );

            locationTreeView = new TreeView<String>(root);

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why its not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why your application doesn't work:

1. You need to make the Controller and the Application separate classes.
2. You should allow the FXML system to inject the TreeView instance rather than creating a new instance (as Aaron points out in his answer).

The way you have your application currently structured what will happen is:

1. The Java system will create an instance of `MyControllerClass` on startup (and invoke it's `start` method).
2. The `FXMLLoader` will create *another instance* of `MyControllerClass` *each time* the `myInterface.fxml` file is loaded.
3. The `FXMLLoader` will create a new `TreeView` instance and perform the FXML injection on the `locationTreeView` member of the *new* `MyControllerClass` instance it creates.
4. The `FXMLLoader` will try to invoke the `initialize` method on the new `MyControllerClass` (of which you have none).
5. The `FXMLLoader` will *not* invoke the `start` method on the *new* `MyControllerClass`.
6. Your original `start` method invocation on your original `MyControllerClass` will continue processing and create another *new* `TreeView` instance which it will set the `locationTreeView` member of the *old* `MyControllerClass` instance to.

---

I updated your code to make the modifications I suggested above and the code now works.  The updated [code is available](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5174074).

A sample screenshot from the running code is:
[image: dynamictreeview]

*MyApplicationClass.java*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/** Sample application to demonstrate programming an FXML interface. */ 
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // load the scene fxml UI.
    // grabs the UI scenegraph view from the loader.
    // grabs the UI controller for the view from the loader.
    final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myInterface.fxml"));
    final Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    final MyControllerClass controller = loader.<MyControllerClass>getController();

    // continuously refresh the TreeItems.
    // demonstrates using controller methods to manipulate the controlled UI.
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
      new KeyFrame(
        Duration.seconds(3), 
        new TreeLoadingEventHandler(controller)
      )
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    // close the app if the user clicks on anywhere on the window.
    // just provides a simple way to kill the demo app.
    root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        stage.hide();
      }
    });

    // initialize the stage.
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myIcon.png")));
    stage.show();
  }

  /** small helper class for handling tree loading events. */
  private class TreeLoadingEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private MyControllerClass controller;
    private int idx = 0;

    TreeLoadingEventHandler(MyControllerClass controller) {
      this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
      controller.loadTreeItems("Loaded " + idx, "Loaded " + (idx + 1), "Loaded " + (idx + 2));
      idx += 3;
    }
  }

  // main method is only for legacy support - java 8 won't call it for a javafx application.
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

*MyControllerClass.java*

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

/** Sample controller class. */ 
public class MyControllerClass {
  // the FXML annotation tells the loader to inject this variable before invoking initialize.
  @FXML private TreeView<String> locationTreeView;

  // the initialize method is automatically invoked by the FXMLLoader - it's magic
  public void initialize() {
    loadTreeItems("initial 1", "initial 2", "initial 3");
  }  

  // loads some strings into the tree in the application UI.
  public void loadTreeItems(String... rootItems) {
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Root Node");
    root.setExpanded(true);
    for (String itemString: rootItems) {
      root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(itemString));
    }

    locationTreeView.setRoot(root);
  }
}
```

*myInterface.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="test.MyControllerClass">
  <TreeView fx:id="locationTreeView" layoutX="0" layoutY="0" prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="471.0" />
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @jewelsea! Nice explanation! And also thank you for coding the right way!

Comment: You don't NEED to separate the classes. You just NEED the 'initialize' method in class MyControllerClass.

Comment: @Nuno it is not good practice to make a JavaFX controller and a JavaFX application the same class as it is both confusing and error prone.  While it may be possible to get such a setup to work, I do not recommend such a solution and would not post it to a public forum.

Comment: I agree as good practice, but the primary stage has a one-to-one relationship with the application class with both joints mandatory. So you write one class too many... (although, this comment was irrelevant)...

Comment: @Nuno please post your solution as an answer if you feel it has merit.

Comment: @jewelsea No. You were right. I got side effects by mixing both concepts (the initialize method seems to run twice), that were solved by separate them. I apologize.

Comment: I can't seem to access the sample code. Anyone have a mirror?

Comment: @starlord7 I updated the answer to inline the sample code from the github link

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In your loadTreeItems() function you are creating a new TreeView instance.  This is replacing the one that is defined in your FXML file and attached to your scene with a new instance that is not part of the scene graph.

To add items to a TreeView that was created via the FXMLLoader you can use the [setRoot()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#setRoot%28javafx.scene.control.TreeItem%29) function.

```
private void loadTreeItems() {

    try {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Root Node");
        root.setExpanded(true);
        root.getChildren().addAll(
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 1"),
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 2"),
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 3")
        );

        locationTreeView.setRoot(root);

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exc.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Aaron. But it didn't work.I've just created a TreeView, without TreeItems. Could it be the issue?

Comment: I mean: created a TreeView in the FXML file.